# Set JAVA_HOME from javapackager to all child applications

Tags: java, javapackager

I have a question about *javapackager*, I'm newbie of this feature.

I need to create an exe (and app for OSX) to be distributed.
I used javapackager to create a bundle with JRE included and I create my setup, all seems to work.
The problem is that if I use from Java (ProcessBuilder) the command:

```
$java -jar foo.jar
```

The OS give me a JRE missing error (if Java is not installed on PC).

All I want is to set the **JAVA_HOME** variable to my bundled JRE from javapackager or a solution that doesn't involve the change of the command line.

I tried *Launch4J* and all works as I expected (it set the temporary PATH and JAVA_HOME variable), so I think this is possible but I don't know what are the parameters involved. 
I prefer to use *javapackager* because it's less OS dependent.

I tried to set from `-Bruntime` but this is not the solution.

Thanks for the help and for ideas to workaround.

Comment: It should be enough to point to main-class in the build file and to *not* strip commands from the bundle.